# How to create a dictionary with multiple values inside another dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I  want to simulate a graph using dictionaries in Python.

```
G = {'a':{'b':3, 'c':4},
     'b':{'a':3, 'c':5},
     'c':{'a':4,'b':5},
   }
```

G is a dictionary where each value is a dictionary which represents adjacent nodes with its weight.

I have the following code:

```
def Graph(nodes):   
        list_nodes = []
        list_adjacent_nodes = []
        graph = {}

    for i in range(nodes):
        node = raw_input(" ID Node %d:" %(i+1))
        list_nodes.append(node)        
        num_adjacent_nodes = input("  Num adjacent nodes '%s':" %(list_nodes[i]))
        list_adjacent_nodes.append([])    
        for j in range(num_adjacent_nodes):
            adjacent_node = raw_input("   ID adjacent nodes %d:" %(j+1))
              list_adjacent_nodes.append[i].append(adjacent_node)  
            weight = input(" Wight (Nodes(%s,%s) ): " %(list_nodes[i],list_adjacent_nodes[i][j] ) )
            graph[list_nodes[i]] = {}
            graph[lista_nodes[i]][list_adjacent_nodes[i][j]] = weight
  return graph
```

However, I get the following result:

```
G = {'a':{'c':4}, 'b':{'c':5}, 'c':{'b':5}, }
```

Where have I gone wrong and how can I return my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite the "inner" dictionary in each iteration of the loop with an empty dictionary. You should do so only if it's missing:

```
if not graph[list_nodes[i]]: # Here!
    graph[list_nodes[i]] = {}
graph[list_nodes[i]][list_adjacent_nodes[i][j]] = weight
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with  if not grafica.get(lista_nodos[i]):